# LINQ2Entity Framework query acting strange

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have strange problem with my query. I have two almost identical situations in which one query is acting as it should be while the other gives errors.

```
           var osobaIme = (from o in db.osobas
                           orderby o.osoba_ime
                           select o.osoba_ime).ToList().Distinct(); 

            if (chkIme.Checked == true && Session["Ime"] != "1")
            {                   
                cbIme.DataSource = osobaIme;
                cbIme.DataBind(); //Here is the error

                Session["Ime"] = "1";
            }

            var osobaPrezime = (from o in db.osobas
                                orderby o.osoba_prezime
                                select o.osoba_prezime).ToList().Distinct();

            if (chkPrezime.Checked == true && Session["Prezime"] != "1")
            {
                cbPrezime.DataSource = osobaPrezime;
                cbPrezime.DataBind();

                Session["Prezime"] = "1";
            }
```

As you can see both queries are pretty much the same, the only difference is the combobox to which the data is binded and the field from the database. When I "activate" the first query (osobaIme) I receive the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The second one (osobaPrezime) works fine.

I know that the error I receive is mostly related to the null value, but in this case it is impossible because it should be showing the correct results (about 500 of them).

I'm clueless, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by activate? Which line throws an error?

Comment: By activating I mean checking the checkbox that does postback which eventually fills the combobox with data. Check the edit for the line with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the query. The problem was in lousy populated database which allowed nulls to be entered for important field (I really don't know what the database designer was thinking of when he was designing it, but that's another story).

Answer (score 1):

Use that full stack reversal error messages to figure out what component generates the error

```
try
{  //;/;
    // your errorneous code goes here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Exception innerEx = ex;
    while(innerEx != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(innerEx.Message);
        innerEx = innerEx.InnerException;
    }
    throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
}
```